# SASS Files in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sass

Is there a way to access SCSS files from the Wordpress Theme editor UI? I have tried moving it to the root, next to my style.css and also leaving it in the SASS folder.

I am building a custom theme and already had SASS running on it locally and am now going to continue development in Wordpress.

Comment: Use the [`wp_theme_editor_filetypes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_theme_editor_filetypes/) filter to add scss/sass as a file extension. Note that it's only available in 4.4 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the file extension before it will show up in the editor. You can do this with the [`wp_theme_editor_filetypes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_theme_editor_filetypes/) filter.

For example:

```
add_filter('wp_theme_editor_filetypes', function ($types) {
    $types[] = 'scss';

    return $types;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. How do I get it to compile into my style.css? None of the sass compiler plugins seem to work with the latest WP version.

Comment: @GrantW ask that as another question. I have no idea, sorry.